# How to retrieve information from xml tspan tag

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am currently using BeautifulSoup to do xml parsing, but don't know how to get information from inside the tspan tag. The the xml I am parsing looks like this:

```
<text
           transform="matrix(0,-1,-1,0,7931,3626)"
           style="font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:92.3259964px;font-family:Arial;-inkscape-font-specification:ArialMT;writing-mode:lr-tb;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="text60264"><tspan
             x="0 61.581444 123.16289 184.74432 251.4037 323.23334 384.81476 410.48138 436.14801 497.72946 559.31091 625.97028 692.62964 754.21112 805.54437 831.211 918.3667 979.94818 1005.6148 1077.4445 1144.1038 1200.515 1226.1816 1256.9261 1318.5076 1390.3373 1421.0818 1446.7484 1472.415 1526.3334 1587.9149 1649.4963 1716.1556 1782.8151 1844.3965 1895.7297 1921.3964 2008.5521 2070.1335 2095.8003 2167.6299 2234.2893 2290.7004"
             y="0"
             sodipodi:role="line"
             id="tspan60262">APPROX. BARREL WEIGHT (KG): &lt;BARREL WEIGHT&gt;</tspan></text>
```

I can get the text from the text tag, but I am trying to get the `x="0 61.581..."` so that I can change it to just `x="0"`. So far my code only gets the tspan xml tags

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


infile = open('1c E37 Face Electric Operation No No.svg', 'r')
contents = infile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')
items = soup.find_all('tspan')
for item in items:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Realised that I just needed to do ````item.get('x')````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have used css selectors as well - by adding in x attribute to selector you will only get elements where that attribute is present

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

s = '''
<text
transform="matrix(0,-1,-1,0,7931,3626)"
style="font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:92.3259964px;font-family:Arial;-inkscape-font-specification:ArialMT;writing-mode:lr-tb;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
id="text60264"><tspan
 x="0 61.581444 123.16289 184.74432 251.4037 323.23334 384.81476 410.48138 436.14801 497.72946 559.31091 625.97028 692.62964 754.21112 805.54437 831.211 918.3667 979.94818 1005.6148 1077.4445 1144.1038 1200.515 1226.1816 1256.9261 1318.5076 1390.3373 1421.0818 1446.7484 1472.415 1526.3334 1587.9149 1649.4963 1716.1556 1782.8151 1844.3965 1895.7297 1921.3964 2008.5521 2070.1335 2095.8003 2167.6299 2234.2893 2290.7004"
 y="0"
 sodipodi:role="line"
 id="tspan60262">APPROX. BARREL WEIGHT (KG): &lt;BARREL WEIGHT&gt;</tspan></text>
'''

soup = bs(s, 'lxml')
print([i['x'] for i in soup.select('tspan[x]')])
```